# C++ - Array of pointers to classes

Tags: c++

I hope someone here can help me.

So this is my problem:
I have a main class and three other classes. Now I want to make an array with each index pointing to one of these classes. I know how to do it with one class like this:

```
Class1* array[10];
```

and then I can use this for every index:

```
array[i] = new Class1;
```

But is it possible to declare an array and then use something like this?

```
array[0] = new Class1;
array[1] = new Class2;
array[2] = new Class3;
```

Kind regards, Synotix

Comment: Which C++ book are you using and how far through it are you?

Comment: If the goal is just to append a number at the end, then yes in some bizarre academic sense, you could do something similar with templates. You should NOT NOT NOT do that though in so many ways. Be a man! Type it out!

Comment: Of course that's possible, as long `Class2` and `Class3` inherit from a virtual `Class1`.

Comment: @Synotix: it seems that you confuse *objects* and *classes*. Surprisingly, nobody has mentioned this yet. In C++, you cannot treat classes as objects like e.g. in Java, which means, among other things, that there is no such thing as a "pointer to a class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes You can do it** But for this Purpose You have to Use Inheritance and Polymorphism in C++.

What you can do is. 
Create a parent class i.e

```
Class parent {

// Some common code here
// Some virtual function here
}
```

Then inherit all of your class like in your case which are Class1 , Class2 , Class3
from **parent** class. Also create a virtual method in the parent class to obtain polymorphism in C++.

In this way You will be able to do this.

```
parent * allClasses[10];

allClasses[1]= new Class1();
allClasses[2]= new Class2();
allClasses[3]= new Class3();
```

Here is a complete Example of what You want. Check this Link
[Can someone explain the benefits of polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147521/can-someone-explain-the-benefits-of-polymorphism)

Comment: @alexvii Bro Sorry to say but its not a professional attitude to Vote down someone's answer and getting aggressive. I did not copied a single bit of your code. I written every line on my own and was writing even before I saw your Answer.

Comment: @alexvii That's a serious allegation. Similar answers are not uncommon.

Comment: 6 minutes later, exactly the same idea?! Sorry but I would have noticed that.

Comment: Make sure the base class has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @alexvii: What's so unthinkable about it? Writing good answers takes time. When I write answers, I usually try to compile any code I post, and I try to verify the claims I make and add references; not to mention that I sometimes consult an English dictionary or look up phrases on Google because I also want the answer to be good from a human-language point of view. In the meanwhile, somebody else may have posted almost the same answer already. That's life.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible if you use a main class as parent and the classes `Class1, Class2 and Class3` should be subclasses of the main class.

If all your classes (1-3) `extend` from the class e.g. `ParentClass` you could write:

```
ParentClass* array[n];

ParentClass* class1 = new Class1();
ParentClass* class2 = new Class2();
ParentClass* class3 = new Class3();
//...
array[0] = class1;
//... classes 2 and 3
```

Here is an [example how to extend](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/47505/) classes in c++.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but what do you want to do with the array? If your classes all have a common base class then you can define your array to contain pointers to that base class then you can add classes to the array as you have done.

In order to use your classes you will need to do it via `virtual` methods on the base class.

A few suggestions: I would suggest your base class has a `virtual` destructor, this means that when you `delete` the elements of the array it will call the destructor on the derived class. Also, I suggest using smart pointers instead of raw pointers so you don't need to call `delete`. Here is an example, I have used a `vector` instead of an array and a class template to define the classes:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyBase {
 public:
  virtual ~MyBase() {}
  virtual void hello() = 0;
};

template<int N>
class MyClass : public MyBase {
 public:
  virtual void hello(){ std::cout << "Hello, I am Number" << N << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> my_classes;

  my_classes.emplace_back(new MyClass<1>());
  my_classes.emplace_back(new MyClass<2>());
  my_classes.emplace_back(new MyClass<3>());

  for(auto& my_class : my_classes)
    my_class->hello();
}
```